# CSS rule that applies to some children but ignores others

Tags: html, css

I have this basic setup:

```
  <ul class='collection'>
    <li class='collection-item'><strong>Name:</strong> Tim</li>
    <li class='collection-item'><strong>Current Location:</strong> Kansas</li>
  </ul>
```

I want a rule that floats the not bold text to the right. Currently I've tried:

```
li > :not(strong){
  float: right;}
```

But it doesn't affect the strong text. If I wrap the not bold text in a `<p>` element and do

```
li > p {
  float: right;}
```

it adds an extra line, which I'd like to avoid. Am I using the `:not` selector incorrectly? Is there another way to accomplish this? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use flexbox, so it can transform plain text into an anonymous flex item.

```css
.collection-item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<ul class='collection'>
  <li class='collection-item'><strong>Name:</strong> Tim</li>
  <li class='collection-item'><strong>Current Location:</strong> Kansas</li>
</ul>
```

You can also try the text align and float tricks.

```css
.collection-item {
  text-align: right;
}

.collection-item strong {
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<ul class='collection'>
  <li class='collection-item'><strong>Name:</strong> Tim</li>
  <li class='collection-item'><strong>Current Location:</strong> Kansas</li>
</ul>
```